# freeDrawingBrush.onMouseMove fix x or y to draw only straight line

Tags: fabricjs

I am trying to draw a straight line making x fix using freeDrawingBrush.

For example:

```
          canvas.isDrawingMode = 1;
          canvas.freeDrawingBrush.color = "purple";
          canvas.freeDrawingBrush.width = 10; 

          canvas._onMouseMoveInDrawingMode = function (e) {
           
                var pointer = canvas.getPointer(e);
                pointer.x = 100;
                
                this.freeDrawingBrush.onMouseMove(pointer);
            
        }
```

this doing the work but it is drawing continuously on mousemove. I want user to be able to draw multiple lines at a fix (for e.g.) x=100 at distances on y-axis.

Update:

I added following code :

```
          canvas._onMouseUpInDrawingMode = function (e) {


            this._isCurrentlyDrawing =  false;
            //canvas.selection = true;
            canvas.isDrawingMode = 0;

            this.freeDrawingBrush.onMouseUp();
            this._handleEvent(e, 'up');

        }
```

This stops drawing continuously but new problem raised. When I enable drawing mode again and try to draw new line it also add previous line to new line

Comment: There is some code in the freedrawing brush that allow you to draw a straight line pressing shift during mouse move. You can look at that code and extend it in order to get your horizontal or vertical line

Comment: Can you please provide me link about freedrawing brush you are talking about... i am not able to find it .. if you can that will be great help. Thanks

Comment: che current master in the repository, the pencil brush

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of research I found the way:

```
var brush = new fabric.PencilBrush(canvas);
canvas.isDrawingMode = 1;
brush.width = 10;
     
canvas._onMouseMoveInDrawingMode = function (e) {
       
    var pointer = canvas.getPointer(e);
    pointer.x = 100;
            
    brush.onMouseDown({x:pointer.x, y:pointer.y});
        
}
```